# Android Combine 3 table in Room and Observe

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have Three tables

1.Message
2.Comment
3.Attachment

**Relation** -> 
Message contain List of {Attachment and Comment}

Comment contain List of {Attachment}

I need to get in this Format

Message->{List of Comments(this include List of Attachments)
 and List of Attachments }

How can i Observe this 3 tables and query these

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with `@Embedded` and `@Relation` in Room, see https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1